# Lorentzian First Variation Formula?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

Let $(N, g)$ be an $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold and $S$ be a submanifold of $N$ of dimension $m$. For $X \in \Gamma(TS)$ define a family of variations in $M$ to be  $$\varphi: S \times  (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \rightarrow M, \hspace{5mm} \varphi(x, s) = \exp_x(sX)$$

so that the surfaces $\varphi_s$ are generated by geodesics eminating from $S$.
Then $\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial s}|_{s=0} = X$ is the variation field. So the First Variation Formula for any fixed surface $\varphi_s$ is

$${\frac{d}{ds}}\left({Vol}(\varphi_s)\right)_{\{s=0\}} = {\int_{\varphi_s}({div}_{\varphi}X)\Omega_{\varphi_s}}$$

I'm wondering if we let $N$ be Lorentzian with $S$ spacelike if this formula still makes sense? I can't see any mention of this generalisation anywhere but see no reason for it not to be true. The only worry I have is if $X$ is null then the zero inner product could potentially lead to singularity issues. However  I only see hand-wavey potential problems, nothing rigorous.

I'm interested in people's thoughts, in particular whether or not $X$'s being null makes a difference.

Comment: You can simply repeat the same calculation as in the Riemannian case and see if it all works.  If there is  possible division by zero, then the formula won't necessarily hold at points where this happens. Nothing will go wrong with the variational formula for a spacelike hypersurface. The main difference between spacelike and null sufaces will appear in the second variation formula.

Comment: Do we not need information about the surfaces $\varphi_s$ near S, as well as $S$, in order to define the derivative? For example, what if $S$ is spacelike but any $\varphi_s$ near $S$ (ie. a small variation) is a null surface? Given that we need local information near $S$ (that is, information about these null $\varphi_s$ surfaces) in order to define the derivative, could these null surfaces cause problems in this scenario?

Comment: The first variation formula is for *any* compactly supported deformation of $S$. If $S$ is spacelike (which is an open condition with respect to the $C^1$ topology), then any sufficiently small compactly supported smooth variation of $S$ will still be spacelike. On the other hand if $S$ is null (which is a closed condition), then there are variations that can make part of $S$ spacelike and other variations that make part of it time-like.

Comment: @Deane: Assume $N$ is Lorentzian, $S$ is spacelike. You say "any sufficiently small compactly supported smooth variation of S will still be spacelike". I've been trying to prove this. For all $\xi \in T_xS$ we have $g(\xi,\xi) > 0$. I want to show for all $\eta \in T_x\varphi_s$, $g(\eta, \eta) > 0$. The obvious thing to do would be to parallel transport $\xi$ along the variation field $X$, but this would mean parallel transporting along a null geodesic which surely must be problematic?

Comment: ^^Too late to edit. I mean of course, for $s$ sufficiently small $\eta \in T_x\varphi_s$ has $g(\eta, \eta) > 0$

Comment: Do everything in local coordinates and use the fact that any surface close to $S$ is a graph over $S$ of a function that is $C^1$ close to zero